# Часть кода, который должен работать, выделяется красным

Tags: android, kotlin, button, kotlinx

Есть код:

```
    import android.content.Intent
    import android.net.Uri
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
    import android.os.Bundle
    import android.view.Menu
    import android.view.MenuItem
    import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest
    import com.semenov.top100currencies.R
    import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_about.*
    import ru.druliks.top100currencies.R
    
    
    class AboutActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_about)
    
            buttonRateApp.setOnClickListener {
                startActivity(Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=${applicationContext.packageName}")))
            }
        }
    }
```

Если вставить этот код в ANdroid Studio, получается следующее:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это исправить

Comment: в вашем импорте библиотеки, которых у вас нет. Проверьте ваш build.gradle

Comment: @VladOrlinskas, оформите, пожалуйста, свой комментарий в виде ответа, чтобы я мог его принять

Answer (score 0):

Судя по коду, buttonRateApp это кнопка. Вы пытаетесь на неё повесить слушатель, не объявляя этой кнопки.

Нужно buttonRateApp идентифицировать, как объект

Comment: там оказалось, что всё дело в этом импорте: import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_about.*